active-backup bond mistakenly detects a missing link
I have two different ISP on the client and one remote server. There is a need for a simple failover tunnel between the client and the server.
I haven’t gotten too complicated yet and created 2 gre tunnels on the client side towards the server, and mutual tunnels on the server side.
As a result, we have gre1 and gre2 for both the client and the server.
Now, if anyone of them is assigned a static pair of addresses, then the client can see the server perfectly inside gre at the moment and vice versa, I would say no problems. Everything responds perfectly, the speed is stable. Beauty!
But these are 2 “different” networks.
I decided to take the quick route to simplify life and create a bond interface in active-backup mode, where the slaves are these two gre tunnels. But the question arose... should we do this on both sides? If so, then there is a possibility that active interfaces on different sides may become “crossed” and nothing will work.
Which bonding mode should I choose for such a solution?
Now I have configured it this way, but every 6 seconds the bond detects a malfunction of one of the slaves and immediately determines the restoration of operation. Although in reality there is no malfunction.
/sbin/ifup gre1 gre2
ip link set gre1 down
ip link set gre2 down
echo "+bond0" > /sys/class/net/bonding_masters
echo "active-backup" > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/mode
ip link addr add 192.168.10.6/24 dev bond0
ip link set bond0 up
echo "+192.168.10.100" > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/arp_ip_target
echo 2000 > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/arp_interval
echo "+gre1" > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/slaves
echo "+gre2" > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/slaves
echo "gre1" > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/primary
ip link set gre1 up
ip link set gre2 up

and link down detection
[454080.990659] bond0: (slave gre1): link status definitely up
[454080.990671] bond0: (slave gre1): making interface the new active one
[454080.990795] bond0: active interface up!
[454087.038717] bond0: (slave gre1): link status definitely down, disabling slave
[454087.038744] bond0: now running without any active interface!
[454091.070820] bond0: (slave gre1): link status definitely up
[454091.070838] bond0: (slave gre1): making interface the new active one
[454091.070936] bond0: active interface up!
[454097.118939] bond0: (slave gre1): link status definitely down, disabling slave
[454097.118966] bond0: now running without any active interface!
[454099.135193] bond0: (slave gre1): link status definitely up
[454099.135206] bond0: (slave gre1): making interface the new active one
[454099.135367] bond0: active interface up!
[454105.183375] bond0: (slave gre1): link status definitely down, disabling slave
[454105.183401] bond0: now running without any active interface!
[454107.199240] bond0: (slave gre1): link status definitely up
[454107.199253] bond0: (slave gre1): making interface the new active one
[454107.199349] bond0: active interface up!

